# Alternative of navigator.connection.type for Website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to get Network and Location Information in my ASP.Net Core MVC Web Application

After Some research I found Navigator API on internet ,

For Getting Location it works perfectly

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      console.log("Latitude : " + position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("Longitude : " + position.coords.longitude);
  });
```

But to get Network Download Speed

```
navigator.connection.downlinkMax
```

And Connection Type

```
navigator.connection.type
```

they return undefined

Is there any other alternative , any JS library to do same ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use below mentioned library for getting connection variables

[NewtworJS](https://github.com/nesk/network.js)

However it too have some limitation

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.connection` is still an experimental feature that appears to really only be available in Chrome right now [based on this MDN Browser Compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection). It's probably coming up undefined because your browser doesn't support it yet.

To determine download speed, you could grab `const timeStart = Date.now()`, request something of a known size from your server, and then grab `const timeEnd = Date.now()` when the request is done.

The download speed would then be `const speed = filesize / (timeEnd - timeStart)`.

Comment: Thanks , but I wont be checking start time and end time here , my purpose is to show speed in a label which get refreshed every 5 second